# Do I need a carnet for travelling in/between countries in southern Africa?

Tags: driving, africa, carnet-de-passage

I live in South Africa, and hope in the future to travel around Southern Africa visiting places such as Botswana, Mozambiqe etc. Do I need a carnet for travelling within Southern Africa?.

Comment: I take it you're specifically asking about travelling with your own vehicle? Is your vehicle registered in South Africa?